# Draw circle connection bar between two (or more) nodes of different tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps, node-connections

I tried to find something as identical as possible to this question but did not find it. If so, please let me know.
I want to connect two nodes that are in different tikzpicture environments through circle connection bar. By default the connection bar code should be close to the tikzpicture environment of the last declared node or isolated to a single tikzpicture but never to the tikzpicture environment of the first declared node, see case 1 and 2. Everything seems (optical illusion?) To work well, but in both cases the nodes do not remain in their original position at either end of the circle connection bar edge, and that is the main issue. Also, if there was a solution it would work for case 3 when using `\newpage` ?

Case 1:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy1) at (30:10cm){motorcycle.1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {motorcycle.2};
\draw[circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["USA" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Case 2:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy1) at (30:10cm){motorcycle.1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {motorcycle.2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["USA" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Case 3 (with `\newpage`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy1) at (30:10cm){motorcycle.1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {motorcycle.2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["USA" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As pointed out by @Henri Menke, I present an attempt to use `remember picture`and `overlay`. I'm not sure exactly how to use these arguments, but after all, I couldn't keep the nodes at either end of it either edges from the `circle connection bar`. Am I doing something incorrectly when using these arguments?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [remember picture,overlay]
(energy1) at (30:10cm){motorcycle.1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {motorcycle.2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[circle connection bar]
(energy1)
  edge["USA" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Following @Henrique Menke's note about the above attempt, I have been able to place the nodes at the end `circle connection bar`but have not been able to maintain their initial positions, although I have tried to change the coordinates of both nodes to be further and further apart. to check if it was really working or was an "optical illusion".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]

        \node [remember picture] (energy1) at (30:30cm){motorcycle.1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \node [remember picture] (energy2) at (90:10cm) {motorcycle.2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\draw[circle connection bar,remember picture, overlay]
(energy1)
  edge["USA" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]
  (energy2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need at least `remember picture` for position-tracking.

Comment: And you probably want to draw the connection bar in an `overlay`

Comment: Also position-tracking does not work across pages.

Comment: Thank. I didn't remember that command. I'll run some tests and see how it works.

Comment: @HenriMenke I have submitted an attempt to use `remember picture`and `overlay`in the original question. If you can see where I may be going wrong in this attempt, I am grateful.

Comment: The `tikzpicture` containing `(energy1)` and `(energy2)` need `remember picture`, the `tikzpicture` with the connection bar needs `remember picture, overlay`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I have updated the original question: I managed to keep the nodes at the edge ends but the nodes are out of their original positions (as well as the edge ends).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97610/discussion-between-diego-bnei-noah-and-henri-menke).

Answer (score 1):

You can draw all in a single tikz environment, without any need to do the hard work of connecting different environments. The option to position the label will help here. This is an example.

The only problem is with the size of the drawing and label, which may be handled by means of text scaling. (maybe)

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (energy1)[label=right:motorcycle.1] at (30:10cm){};
\node (energy2)[label=left:motorcycle.2] at (90:10cm){};
\draw[circle connection bar]
(energy1)%
edge["USA" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}]%
(energy2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]